# Converting a string to int, for a SQL Database call

Tags: c#, type-conversion, conventions, sql

I am trying to execute a SQL select statement to retrieve my id, then increment the id. I can select from the database just fine. But when I try to convert the string to a int, I get the error of format exception was caught

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Here is my code:

```
var sql = new SQL_Statements();
var string_sql_id ="";
var string_sql_select = "select * from is_inventory where id =(select max(id) from is_inventory)";

var sql_ds = sql.SelectFromDB(string_sql_select);

int DataIndex;

if (sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows.Count > 0)
   for (DataIndex = 0; DataIndex <= sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows.Count - 1; DataIndex++)
   {
       (sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString();
       string_sql_id ="CurData";
       var int_sql_id = Convert.ToInt32(string_sql_id);
       ++int_sql_id;
   }
```

On the second to last line of code is where it throws the exception. I have tried to change the convert to something else like double, but that didn't work either. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You're using so many vars that I can't even tell what you're trying to do. Can you add some comments maybe?

Comment: You need to store the result of (sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString(); in a local variable

Comment: Prefacing all your variables with their type is really going to anger the next dev that reads your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the line immediately before you're convert line, you set `string_sql_id ="CurData";`.  "CurData" is not an integer, and attempting to convert it to one will not work.

try this instead;

```
string_sql_id = (sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString();
```

Comment: in that case, its highly likely that you are either retrieving the wrong piece of data, or retrieving it incorrectly.  What, _EXACTLY_, is returned by this statement: `(sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString()`?

Comment: I replaced string_sql_id ="CurData"; with string_sql_id = (sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString();

Comment: It still looks like you're doing some redundant conversion here - is the "id" field of "CurData" actually stored as an int in the returned DataSet? If so, it should be able to be cast to an int. If "id" can ever return null, you'll need to check for DBNull first though.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason you're fetching the value then discarding it, and then trying to convert the string `CurData` to an int.

```
(sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString();
string_sql_id ="CurData";
var int_sql_id = Convert.ToInt32(string_sql_id);
```

The value of `string_sql_id` is *always* just `CurData` then - how did you expect it to be anything else?

The value in the datatable should already be an integer, so you shouldn't need any parsing:

```
var id = (int) sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"];
```

(You *may* find that it's a `long` instead of an `int` - it depends on the type of your field.)

You should avoid unnecessary string conversions where possible. In this case it's not clear why you're using a `DataTable` at all. You could just use a `DataReader` - and if you change you code to just select the max ID, you can just use `ExecuteScalar` to get a single value. Your current approach is very convoluted.

Comment: to be perfectly honest, I like your answer better than mine :(.  lol.

Answer (score 3):

```
string_sql_id ="CurData";
var int_sql_id = Convert.ToInt32(string_sql_id);
```

You're trying co convert to int string "CurData"

Comment: Quite surprised this has more up votes than Jon's answer - especially when there is no further explanation on how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert the `string` "CurData" to an integer which is what is throwing the exception.

```
 string_sql_id ="CurData";
 var int_sql_id = Convert.ToInt32(string_sql_id);
```

I assume you mean to assign `string_sql_id` to the `Row ID`:

```
 string_sql_id = sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["id"]).ToString();
```

Then you can attempt to convert:

```
 var int_sql_id = Convert.ToInt32(string_sql_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying convert primitive string type to Int. So it is something to do with your logic.

```
string_sql_id ="CurData";
var int_sql_id = Convert.ToInt32(string_sql_id);
```

**Note**: If you intend to work with Identity ( Incrementing field ) then I advise not to explicitly create incremental fields say *Identity* columns. Try to use database built in feature which generate it for you. Google it on how to defined AUTO INCREMENT Field in SQL or the db which you prefer.